# How to limit Django Model foreign key field to filtered list of same Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is the model i am using, I want to filter qc by type

```
class ServiceCenter(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    qc = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCenter, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to=ServiceCenter.objects.filter(type="Some type"))
```

Comment: Also if we can limit the choices by property which returns boolean, or by a static method which produces the list needed to limit the choices, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Django docs, they're pretty clear on this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

This will do the job:

`limit_choices_to={'type':"Some type"}`